# Emacs Keeps Data Even After I Close It + Doesn't Reload `.emacs`

Tags: init-file, emacsclient, server

Even after I close emacs with `C-x C-c`, it seems that it keeps some state saved: When I open it again, I can, for example, still see the old content of the `*Messages*` buffer. Also, it doesn't seem to be reloading any changes I make in my `.emacs` init file.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are (perhaps unknowingly) running emacs as a client-server pair and `C-x C-c` only closes the client connection. You can use `M-x kill-emacs` to kill both the client and the server. Opening emacs after this reloads everything from scratch.